# Issue with using percentile_cont function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

This is my table

> ID     Total
>   1       2019.21
>   3       87918.32
>   2       562900.3
>   3       982688.98
>   1       56788.34
>   2       56792.32
>   3       909728.23

Now I would like to find the 25th,50th,75th,90th and 100th percentile of the values (Total) in the above Table. Assume my table consists of Whole Lot of data (some 2 Million Records of the same format) . I've Used the Following code :

**CODE :**

```
 SELECT  percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Total) as disc_func
 FROM my_table
```

The Error I've come across :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
>   LINE 3:   percentile_disc(0.5)  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY total...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use PostgreSQL < 9.4 . It does not support WITHIN GROUP

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Thanks, Man. That's really Helpful.